# OpenCMIS/dotcmis: How to find whether a server has a particular capability?

Tags: cmis, dotcmis, opencmis

Using [OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) (or [dotcmis](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html)), after getting a Repository object from a repository, how to check whether it has a particular capability?

For instance, whether CapabilityChanges is set to `all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit nicer:

```
if ( repository.Capabilities.ChangesCapabilities == CapabilityChanges.All ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way to do it, but now I am using this:

```
if ( repository.Capabilities.ChangesCapabilities.GetCmisValue().Equals("all") )
  { ... }
```